# Problem with accentued char when reading appsettings.json with builder

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0

I am reading the configuration file appsettings.json with the builder;

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                                            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Helper.jsonpath, "appsettings.json"));
    Helper.config = builder.Build();
    //same result : P�le emploi instead of Pôle emploi
    var tt = Helper.config.GetSection("partooApi:types:APE").GetValue<string>("title");
    var ttt = Helper.config["partooApi:types:APE:title"];
    var tttt = Helper.config.GetSection("partooApi:types:APE:title").Get<string>();
```

i have the result `P�le emploi` instead of `Pôle emploi`

my appsettings.json has nothing special:

```
"partooApi": {
  "types": {
      "APE": {
        "title": "Pôle emploi",
        "grpname": "Agences",
        "grpid": 10661
      }
     :
```

I dont see options to encode, am i missing something in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if appsettings.json is saved as UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, json MUST be utf-8, according to standard.

Comment: thanks its the reason, i dont know why the property of the file has changed, maybe a wrong process. thnak to point this